# Tiny MCE not working in IE9 when using document.domain

Tags: tinymce

I am using the latest version of `TinyMCE` which will render in IE9 but I cannot interact with it.

Removing `document.domain` will allow it work again, but I need `document.domain` to make the popup windows in tinyMCE work in my setup.

I have tried using `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />` and such but this doesn't seem to make any difference.